# Custom Object / Instance name is not reflecting in server for LwM2M custom Object

Tags: lwm2m, oma, leshan

I have created few custom objects within the range of (26241-32768). As per [OMA registry spec](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/wp/omna/lwm2m/lwm2mregistry.html), we need not have to register the custom objects which are in the range of 26241-32768. I have used lwm2m  Leshan 1.0 server and lwm2m IOWA 1.0 client. When these custom objects get displayed in the Leshan server UI, the name of an object and the instance is not displayed properly. As shown in the attached image, Object name and Instance name is not getting displayed properly. Is it possible to display the name of the Object and Object Instance in server UI without registering the custom objects with OMA? Is there any other possibilities of displaying the name in the server?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Servers have no way to know the representation of an object not registered, they have to be provisioned with the XML to parse their contents and in return to display the information properly on their Web Interface.

For Leshan Server:
•   You need to run your own instance of the Server. When you launch the Server, you have the possibility to provide a folder where your XML are located such as:
o   java -jar ./leshan-server-demo.jar --modelsfolder XML_PATH

For Connecticut:
•   You need to send your XML files to Ioterop, and they will provision their Server with them. Today, there is no public API for it.